# CSS height transition on removal of style="display:none;"

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, javascript-framework, vee-validate

I have html this is basically like this:

```
<span>
  <input name="checked_field" type="text" />
  <p class="has-warning danger" style="display:none;">{{ error.first() }}</p>
</span>
```

The `display:none` is added by JavaScript at load time.  It is removed if the user types an invalid value in `checked_field`.

Since the framework controls visibility by simply *removing* `style="display:none;"`, I am wondering: Is it possible to transition the height and visibility by pure CSS rules when `display:none` is removed via JavaScript?  Again, given that I'm not able to add a 2nd class, but am stuck with the JavaScript framework removing a *style*.

Comment: You can't transition height from display:none with pure CSS afaik. You can do it with a vue transition if you define a specific height or do the `max-height` hack.  You can also use this library I wrote to transition from `display: none` to `height: auto`, https://github.com/guanzo/vue-smooth-height

Comment: Accepted answer does give a CSS only solution, however your component is well-worth studying and I will do so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this by overriding the `display:none` property.

```
.has-warning, .has-warning[style*='display:none'] {
    transition: all 1s;
    display: block !important;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.has-warning:not([style*='display:none']) {
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/165903/

*WARNING!* CSS will see `display:none` as different from `display: none` (space in between) so if it doesn't work at first, check this.

Comment: I would call that an elegant approach.  I went ahead and updated your jsfiddle, especially setting the initial `height:0` transitioning to `height: inherit`.  However I'm not sure the actual _slide_ is working.. https://jsfiddle.net/sfullman/dkecm1hv/

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it helped you :)

Comment: By the way, setting it to initial doesn't work. you need to set the height into an actual unit to make the transition work.  initial, inherit, auto values won't animate the height, however the opacity still works. :)

Answer (score 0):

it really easy

```js
const dropDownSubInput = ref(false) //nuxt 3
```

```css
.subForm {
  width: inherit;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.formActive {
  .form {
    box-shadow: 0 41px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    .subForm {
      max-height: 1000px !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="formSection" :class="dropDownSubInput ? 'formActive' : ''">
      <div class="form">
        <form @submit.prevent>
          <input type="text"
                 placeholder="Введите слово или название"
                 v-model="searchInput"
                 @click="dropDownSubInput = true"
          />

          <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'fa-magnifying-glass']"/>
        </form>

        <div class="subForm">
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```